# Bootstrap 3 - Button height match panel (CSS3)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

**EDIT**
For those of you stumbling over this post, I have found that there is a "new" standard called Flexbox. This allows you do what I want to do: [Flexbox demos](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/)

I am trying to get the following effect:
[image]

However, I get this:
[image]

See jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abehnaz/8sPn7/3/

I tried `height: 100%` in CSS, but I had no luck. I think this might have to do with the fact that either  the button style takes precedence over the height setting, or that the panel takes a dynamic height based on its contents (in this case, the image).

Is there a cross-browser/pure CSS way to make the button height match the panel height (with appropriate padding and fitting of content?)

Thanks!

HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-object pull-left">
            <button class="btn btn-info option-button">A</button>
            <img src="holder.js/200x100" />
        </div>
        <div class="media-body">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.option-button {
    height:100%;
}
```

**EDIT: ** To get to a solution that was acceptable, I ended up using the button in a media object. It does not automatically fit the entire height, but it does the job. It helped to apply the `.btn-lg` class.

Comment: jsfiddle link is not working

Comment: You need to show code.

Comment: Shoot. I lost the jsFiddle. Working on putting it back up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order for the browser to understand what 100% actually represents, you must give the containing div, in this case your `media-object` div, a height **or** have *all* parent divs have height 100%.

Think of it this way, the browser needs some number to start 100%, and when all parent divs have `height: 100%;` it uses the viewport (window size) for this number.  If you have ever tried to do a sticky footer you have probably run into similar problems.

Here is a jsfiddle with a specified height:
http://jsfiddle.net/8sPn7/5/

Here is another jsfiddle with everything height 100% (a quick a dirty way to show you the 100% rule):
http://jsfiddle.net/8sPn7/6/

Comment: Uh, that's the same fiddle from the question. I think you forgot to save.

Comment: @jbaum012, I somewhat understand the concept that you are talking about. The issue is that the content is going to be dynamically populated. This means that the text *or* the image could theoretically set the height. Also, the text could be shorter than the button. Perhaps a "calc" CSS property would help?

Comment: @DiodeDan Things get tricky, as I'm sure you have noticed.  In my experience it is easier to use a little javascript to handle these kinds of problems, but if you need to stay purely css I can see what else I can come up with.

Comment: I completely agree. I wonder if I could use the display: table property for the panel, and then use a display: table-cell for the internal elements.

Answer (score 7):

**Bootstrap 4 :**
add these classes `d-flex align-items-stretch` in the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your exact goal, this may not help, but adding `height:100px` to the containing `div` makes your `height:100%` work as expected. It looks like when the `div` expands to hold the image, that expansion isn't being carried through to the button like you'd expect.

Another thing that fixes the height is setting the button to `position:absolute`... but that's silly and unhelpful, unless it happens to be a fixed-width button and you can add a `margin-left` or something to space the rest of the content around it.

Comment: The `position: absolute` way is the same way Bootstrap accomplishes its fixed navbar: it tells you to add padding to the `<body>` to take the space of the navbar. If the button is a fixed width, this is a good option.